# How to disable text selection on JTextArea Swing

Tags: java, swing

I don't want the user to select the content on `JTextArea`.  I use `setEditable(false)` but it's not working. How to disable this feature of `JTextArea` component. Could you give me advise. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You want to disable the "selection" support

Comment: I don't know if you can, you could make the selection background the same color as the text area's background and the selection foreground the same color as the text area's foreground, that'll "mask" it.  Alternatively, you could use a `JLabel` and wrap the text in `<html>...</html>` which might provide you with some text wrapping capabilities, without the selection or editabity

Comment: @MadProgrammer: This is special case, I have to force use TextArea, but I don't want the author to selection the text on textarea....

Comment: *"Could you give me advise."* Don't attempt such a silly thing.  What is your interest in suppressing the user's ability to select information seen in the app.?  I'd bet that whatever that objectives is, suppressing the ability of user's to select text will not fulfill it..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the "mark" equal to the "dot" of the caret. When these values are equal there is no text selection:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class NoTextSelectionCaret extends DefaultCaret
{
    public NoTextSelectionCaret(JTextComponent textComponent)
    {
        setBlinkRate( textComponent.getCaret().getBlinkRate() );
        textComponent.setHighlighter( null );
    }

    @Override
    public int getMark()
    {
        return getDot();
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JTextField textField1 = new JTextField("No Text Selection Allowed");
        textField1.setCaret( new NoTextSelectionCaret( textField1 ) );
        textField1.setEditable(false);

        JTextField textField2 = new JTextField("Text Selection Allowed");

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("No Text Selection Caret");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(textField1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(textField2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If you would like to just disable text selection on any swing control such as `JtextArea` you can use the coding below:

```
JtextArea.setHighlighter(null);
```

This one line of coding will help disable the text selection and can be placed in the constructor or within a initialized method upon Frame execution.

Hope this helps

Comment: This disables visual display of highlighted text, but it does not disable text selection

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party, but here are my findings.  I had tried using [`setEnabled(false)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setEnabled-boolean-) on a `JTextPane` displaying static (not user-modifiable) content such as line numbers (for another text component).  This one alone prevents the component from getting focus and text selection on it:

```java
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("Static text");
        textArea.setEnabled(false);
```

My problem with `setEnabled(false)` is that it forces a single [`disabledTextColor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getDisabledTextColor--) for all of the text (I've traced it down to [`javax.swing.text.GlyphView.paint()`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/251e065a1721/src/java.desktop/share/classes/javax/swing/text/GlyphView.java#L380-L384)), while I want to style individual lines/chunks.  I've finally tried [`setFocusable(false)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setFocusable-boolean-) that appears to satisfy both needs:

- Not user focusable and no user selection on it;
- Custom text color could be applied to individual parts of the content, or it just doesn't change the text color to the *disabled* one.

The complete solution needs additional [`setEditable(false)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setEditable-boolean-) to prevent the mouse cursor from changing but that's it – two properties:

```java
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("Static text");
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        textArea.setFocusable(false);
```

Comment: Ah thanks I had issues with other technichs involving the highlighter, and the caret deinstallation ; `setEditable(false)` and `setFocusable(false)` works well !