# How to disable the ability to highlight in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextarea

I am looking for a way to disable the ability to highlight in the JTextArea.

Currently this is my JTextArea:

```
textArea1 = new JTextArea();
textArea1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 1));
DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret) textArea1.getCaret(); // this line and the line below was inspired by a comment found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623287/how-to-always-scroll-to-bottom-of-text-area
caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);
textArea1.setEditable(false);
JScrollPane scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(textArea1);
```

I use the DefaultCaret class to always have the JTextArea viewpoint pushed to the bottom at all times and `textArea1.setEditable(false)` to stop end users being able to type anything in.

However, if I highlight text the DefaultCaret method just stops working. Once you highglight the text, the JTextArea does not stick to the bottom anymore.

Comment: This answer was originally closed as a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32515391/how-to-disable-text-selection-on-jtextarea-swing. Yes, that does answer the topic title. However if you read further you will see that the real problem is: *Once you highlight the text, the JTextArea does not stick to the bottom anymore* - So I opened up the question to provide suggestion on how to solve the actual problem, not the assumed problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Once you highglight the text, the JTextArea does not stick to the bottom anymore.

The problem is that automatic scrolling will only happen when the caret is at the end of the Document.

Highlighting text isn't strictly the problem. The problem is the user clicking the mouse anywhere in the text area since that will change the caret position.

So if you want automatic scrolling to always be enabled the proper solution would be to remove the `MouseListener` and `MouseMouseMotionListener` from the text area to prevent all mouse related activity.

Or as a simple hack you could always reset the caret position of the Document:

```
textArea.addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter()
{
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
    {
        JTextArea textArea = (JTextArea)e.getSource();
        textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());
    }
});
```

Edit:

Lets assume you have multiple text areas to have the same functionality. You don't need to create a custom listener for each text area. The listener can be shared. The code could be written as:

```
    MouseListener ml = new new MouseAdapter()
    {
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
        {
            JTextArea textArea = (JTextArea)e.getSource();
            textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());
        }
    };

    textArea1.addMouseListener(ml);
    textArea2.addMouseListener(ml);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this camickr. I actually discovered it was the user clicking the mouse and opened another question based on that. This method you have provided works perfectly. Really happy about this :)

Could you explain to me how the method works though? I am trying to understand why you make another JTextArea with the current textArea1 being assigned to the newly created text area instead of just using the current textArea1. Once again, thank you so much this is perfect!

Comment: I am not making another JTextArea. I am just getting the reference to the text area that you clicked on. This is a technique for writing a generic listener that can be shared by multiple components. See edit for a simple example.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense, thank you so much. I am used to writing anonymous listeners so I did not pay attention to the fact that that was not anonymous. Really cool, learnt something new!