# JFrame adding two mouselisteners causing glitchy drag effect

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jtextpane

So I have an undecorated JFrame I tried to add this framedraglistener to the JFrame and that worked in a way.
But I can't drag the frame if my mouse is inside the text pane inside the Frame.

So I tried to also add it to text pane and that kinda worked but is causing a glitchy effect because I am adding two different mouse listeners.

Here you can see the glitchy effect the mouse listeners are causing. https://streamable.com/3yijqq

So how can I either cancel one of the mouse listeners when clicking inside the text pane or turn the two mouse listeners into one that works both on the JFrame and inside the text pane so it won't be causing that glitchy effect

Here is the FrameDragListener

```
FrameDragListener frameDragListener = new FrameDragListener(this);
jTextPane1.addMouseListener(frameDragListener);
jTextPane1.addMouseMotionListener(frameDragListener);

public static class FrameDragListener extends MouseAdapter {

    private final JFrame frame;
    private Point mouseDownCompCoords = null;

    public FrameDragListener(JFrame frame) {
        this.frame = frame;
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        mouseDownCompCoords = null;
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        mouseDownCompCoords = e.getPoint();
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        Point currCoords = e.getLocationOnScreen();
        frame.setLocation(currCoords.x - mouseDownCompCoords.x, currCoords.y - mouseDownCompCoords.y);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be consistent. In `mousePressed`, you are using `e.getPoint()`, in `mouseDragged`, you are using `e.getLocationOnScreen()`. Just use `getLocationOnScreen()` every time.

Comment: Mind that `e.getPoint()` returns a point relative to the event source component, which is causing the problems when you add this listener to other components than the frame. You can use `mouseDownCompCoords = e.getLocationOnScreen(); mouseDownCompCoords.x -= frame.getX(); mouseDownCompCoords.y -= frame.getY();` within `mousePressed`, to always get the reference point relative to the frame. Then, the `mouseDragged` method can stay as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    Point currCoords = frame.getLocation();
    Point newMouseDownCompCoords = e.getPoint();
    frame.setLocation(currCoords.x + newMouseDownCompCoords.x - mouseDownCompCoords.x, currCoords.y + newMouseDownCompCoords.y - mouseDownCompCoords.y);
}
```

It worked for me:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main {

    public static class FrameDragListener extends MouseAdapter {
        
        private final JFrame frame;
        private Point mouseDownCompCoords = null;

        public FrameDragListener(final JFrame frame) {
            this.frame = frame;
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(final MouseEvent e) {
            mouseDownCompCoords = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(final MouseEvent e) {
            mouseDownCompCoords = e.getPoint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(final MouseEvent e) {
            Point currCoords = frame.getLocation();
            Point newMouseDownCompCoords = e.getPoint();
            frame.setLocation(currCoords.x + newMouseDownCompCoords.x - mouseDownCompCoords.x, currCoords.y + newMouseDownCompCoords.y - mouseDownCompCoords.y);
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            final JTextPane jTextPane1 = new JTextPane();
            jTextPane1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.CYAN.darker(), 5));
            jTextPane1.setText("Some text...");
            
            final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Drag the text pane");
            
            final FrameDragListener frameDragListener = new FrameDragListener(frame);
            jTextPane1.addMouseListener(frameDragListener);
            jTextPane1.addMouseMotionListener(frameDragListener);
            
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.getContentPane().add(jTextPane1);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

The only problem with this code, is if you *grab* the `JTextPane` **really close to some edge** (eg the left edge) and drag outside the frame bounds (eg at the left side). But if you grab the `JTextPane` a couple of pixels away from all edges, then you should see a normal drag as I saw. To solve this at-the-edge problem you may want to use the `java.awt.MouseInfo` class to always get the location of the user's mouse pointer even when outside the frame's bounds. I will test the idea of the `MouseInfo` shortly and let you know.

Please post an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so you can get better answers.

### Edit 1:

Here follows the code which utilizes the `MouseInfo` class...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main {

    public static class FrameDragListener extends MouseAdapter {
        
        private final JFrame frame;
        private Point mouseDownCoords = null;

        public FrameDragListener(final JFrame frame) {
            this.frame = frame;
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(final MouseEvent e) {
            mouseDownCoords = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(final MouseEvent e) {
            mouseDownCoords = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(final MouseEvent e) {
            Point currCoords = frame.getLocation();
            Point newMouseDownCoords = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
            frame.setLocation(currCoords.x + newMouseDownCoords.x - mouseDownCoords.x, currCoords.y + newMouseDownCoords.y - mouseDownCoords.y);
            mouseDownCoords = newMouseDownCoords;
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Drag the text pane");

            final FrameDragListener frameDragListener = new FrameDragListener(frame);

            final JTextPane jTextPane1 = new JTextPane();
            jTextPane1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.CYAN.darker(), 5));
            jTextPane1.setText("Some text...");

            jTextPane1.addMouseListener(frameDragListener);
            jTextPane1.addMouseMotionListener(frameDragListener);

            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.getContentPane().add(jTextPane1);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

It works, but the problem persists. It may be due to the text of the `JTextPane` being selected and unselected. I will try to fix it and then let you know again.

### Edit 2:

Seems like indeed the selection/unselection of text of the `JTextPane` is causing the problem. Because when I substituted the `JTextPane` with a `JLabel` it worked fine. So the question now is: **What do you want to happen when the user drags inside the `JTextPane`? Do you want the text to be selected, or the frame being dragged? There is a conflict between those options.**

I would suggest you to just add an empty space (eg an empty `JPanel`) at the top, where the user is supposed to grab the (undecorated) frame and add the `FrameDragListener` instance to that, instead of the `JTextPane` or any contents of the user's interface.

Comment: Hello instead of the text being selected I want to move the frame without running the other listener

Comment: Hi. To disable highlighting of text you can use the code `jTextPane1.setHighlighter(null);` for the `JTextPane` (as seen in [an answer of a corresponding question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38219870)). Although the problem of glitching when fast-dragging from an edge of the `jTextPane1` persists.